# how to fix this svg file to display properly

Tags: python, svg

I just used a python program to generate a SVG file: out2.svg

All files are here: https://github.com/jeremy886/svg_crossworder

When I use Adobe Illustrator, I can view it and export it to PNG correctly. But if I open it in a browser like Firefox or Finder, it is not displayed correctly (only a corner of the picture). The desire file is like: out2-adobe.png

I also want to convert the SVG file to PNG (or any image format can be read by pillow and reportlab) by a program like CairoSVG instead of manually using Adobe Illustrator.

How do I fix the SVG file to achieve that?
I generated the SVG file from this program: make_crossword.py

I suspect I need to fix these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.2201;stroke-linecap:square;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.2201;stroke-linecap:square;}
    .st2{font-family:'CourierNewPSMT';}
    .st3{font-size:64px;}
    .st4{font-family:'TimesNewRomanPSMT';}
    .st5{font-size:36px;}
    .st6{enable-background:new    ;}
</style>
<g>
    <polyline class="st0" points="0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0   "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0    "/>
</g>
<g>
    <polyline class="st0" points="100,0 100,100 200,100 200,0   "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="100,0 100,100 200,100 200,0    "/>
</g>
[delete...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewBox values don't seem to be consistent with the data

```
viewBox="0 0 6120 7920"
```

seems closer to what you want. Adjust further as appropriate.

Comment: viewBox="0 0 2000 1900"